# Sending Via PIC18F97J60 EUSART

Tags: microcontroller, pic, serial, uart

When trying to send and receive using a [PIC18F97J60](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/39762a.pdf) and [MAX232](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/max232.pdf) using a program written with the C18 compiler, I am only able to transmit data.  For receiving, I have tried at least 50 methods but none are working. I even tried the software on multiple micro-controller boards to check for a hardware problem but none of the boards ever receive anything. I believe that the following items are correct:

- My clock is perfect at 41.6667MHz
- My baud generation is perfect
- My hardware is OK (some other IIIrd party hex code able to receive also)
- My host PC, its COM port, and the serial cable are OK

Can anyone guide with probable areas I may be missing?

------------------ FURTHER CLARIFICATIONS -------------------------------------------

Thanks Olin for helping, you are great man. Sorry for not putting my question correctly. Please note:

I was trying to do serial I/O to write a boot loader for the PIC18F97J60 myself as my vendor's supplied boot loader stops sending/receiving with PCloader software after a partial user application hex download.  It also ensures that RS232 port is able to both send and receive.  Moreover, Microchip's boot loader described in [AN1310](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/01310a.pdf) also stucks on receiving data.

My sample application (a bootloader) is able to transmit but never receives anything.  I'm in soup: either I need a new boot loader or my application must work. I have never faced such a problem in my 12 years of development and I am feeling like a fool.

Other details as you requested are as follows:

1. I had 10-12 PIC18F97J60 cards with MAX232 on C6/C7 for Serial I/O. The problem is the same for all boards (of different batches).
2. I wish to do 9600 baud, 8 bit, no parity, 1 stop, no handshake, no interrupt data exchange with RealTerm (*Better Than Hyperterminal - Displays HEX Code*).
3. My clock and baud rate calculations are perfect for 41.6667MHz. I have set `OSCTUNE = 0x40` and `BAUDCON = 1084`. I am able to receive perfectly on the PC with RealTerm.
4. My program not able to receive anything on the PIC but able to transmit.
5. I tried polling as well as interrupt but nothing works.

Snippet of code is as follows:

```
void putchar(unsigned char Char)
{
    //Wait for (TSR==1)
    while(TXSTA1bits.TRMT!=1);
    //Trasmit Current Data
    TXREG1= Char;
    //Wait for (TSR==1)
    while(TXSTA1bits.TRMT!=1);
}

void putstr(unsigned char *String)
{
     do
     {
         putchar((*String));
     }while(*String++);
    //CR
     putchar(CR);
    //LF
    putchar(LF);
}

void main(void)
{
    unsigned char RS232[] = "RS-232";
    OSCTUNE = 0x40;
    TXSTA1 = 0x24;
    RCSTA1 = 0x90;
    BAUDCON1=0x08;
    SPBRGH1=0x04;
    SPBRG1=0x3C;

while(1)
{
    putstr(RS232);
    Delay10KTCYx(200);
    if(PIR1bits.RC1IF == 1)
    {
            MYChar = RCREG1; //*** No OERR & FERR present, RC1IF never gets set ***
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I think a few more details are needed in order to help effectively - e.g. which end (PC or PIC) is not receiving? It looks like the PIC from what you say? what baud rate? What software on PC? Have you checked with scope/logic analyser? If so what did you see? Are you using handshaking? Anything else you can think of to give a decent picture (maybe a code snippet, etc)

Comment: Since your hardware is OK, the problem is firmware.  Please reduce your code to only receive a character and toggle a pin.  Then share this code with us.  (It is likely you will find the bug yourself during the process of making this simplified test case.)

Comment: Why are you YELLING at us?

Comment: Whenever someone has a problem where things aren't working and they say something is "perfect", it immediately throws suspicion on that thing. Never have the attitude that a bug can't be a particular thing until you prove what caused the bug by fixing it. Any other attitude is less than mature and undermines your credibility when you ask others for help.  It is pointless to help those that don't suspect everything especially themselves.

Answer (score 2):

One annoying misfeature of the UART on every PIC I've worked with is that a data overrun error will shut down the receiver until code disables and re-enables it.  It is thus imperative to have code that will periodically check the overrun-error flag and, if it is set, disable and re-enable the UART receive function.  Otherwise if the receive buffer overruns, you won't just lose a received byte--you'll lose all data forevermore.

I'm not really sure why Microchip designed their UARTs this way.  My guess would be that in early PICs a receive overrun would cause the receive state machine to lose frame sync, and that disabling the receiver was considered preferable to receiving randomly-framed data (I might agree with them on that point, though I would consider dropping whole bytes while maintaining sync to be better still); later PICs maintained the behavior for compatibility, despite substantial redesigns of the UART subsystem.

In any case, the PIC's UART implementation is what it is.  Check to ensure that the UART receiver is enabled and the receive-overflow isn't tripped.  If not, disable the UART receive function and re-enable it.  Note, btw, that on some PICs the master disable for the UART function will not disable the receiver; you need to clear and re-set the receiver enable.

Answer (score 0):

Before you can find any bug, you have to get into the mindset that the chips are working correctly and that you messed up somewhere.  I have done UART communication on almost the same chip (18F67J60) and even the same clock frequency.  These things work.

First, I would check all your assumptions.  How do you know your clock is really right?  How do you know your baud rate is right?  Have you checked the timing of individual bits on a scope?  Other code can receive using the same hardware, so that's a convincing argument it is OK.  That means it's almost certainly a firmware bug, which is also the most likely guess even without the additional information.

The obvious answer is therefore that you messed up something in the UART driver.  You haven't provided any code, and I wouldn't want to look at it anyway, especially since it's in C.  However, that's where your problem is.

You can look at my examples of UART code for a PIC 18.  One of them is even in a networking project for a 18F67J60.  Go to http://www.embedinc.com/pic/dload.htm and install the PIC Development Tools release.  In the SOURCE > PIC directory you will find a generic template UART driver module.  In the SOURCE > NETW directory you will find a whole project that includes a UART driver.  The file name is NET1C_UARTT.ASPIC.

### Added:

You have now provide a code snippet.  Since you are able to receive the bytes sent by the PIC, the baud rate and clock setup is probably right.  However, you still haven't done some of the basic things you were asked to months ago.  **Look at the UART receive pin right at the PIC and see if there are proper characters there**.  The divides the problem into two areas: bad sending on the PC thru the hardware right up to the PIC, and bad receiving in the PIC firmware.  Keep dividing down the problem until you get to a small enough area you can see what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things spring to mind looking at the code:

Where is MyChar defined?
I can't see any setting of TRISC7 (although it should be set on reset) to make sure it is an input. 
Also, try removing the sent data (the putstr(RS232)) and clearing CREN and resetting it before each interrupt flag check in case there is an error condition present.